# The word landscape as modifying a head noun

Tags: expressions

I want to use **landscape experience** in sentences contrasting it with **aesthetic experience** and **spatial experience** .

The term **landscape** though is commonly taken as a noun.

How could I indicate that I intend it as an adjective which modifies the noun **experience** ?

Comment: Just use it. Nouns can be used attributively (think *door handle*).

Comment: Certainly there are common terms such as "landscape architect".

Comment: @Hot Licks: Which at least allows me to get my head around the possibility that some architects have landscape experience and others don't (despite Andrew's guidance, I wasn't getting anywhere with *landscape handles* or *door experiences* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers You've never experienced a door?! You haven't lived!

Comment: A. Leach: When nouns are used attributively it seems that they are read as "something _of_ something else" (like in handle _of_ a door).  A door experience implies thus experience of a door (or doors) and "landscape experience" as  experience of a landscape.

Comment: By contrast, the attributes 'spatial' or 'aesthetic' refer to a quality which can be applied to many different things. So, when contrasting, I am bound to introduce considerable ambiguity unless I give a long explanation each time.

Comment: Nevertheless, Jorge, it is common in everyday English speech to talk about things like "war experience," park experience," "hotel experience," and "restaurant experience"—each of which involves treating a noun as a modifier. I think "landscape experience" falls easily in line with those other examples.

Answer (score 1):

One might run a "landscape business" (ie, be a "landscape contractor"), operate a "landscape store" (or "landscape center"), etc. The term, in this sense, is generally used to refer to the activity of creating a landscape, vs the static properties of said landscape.

"Landscape experience" is a bit non-idiomatic, though it would be readily understood. Better might be something like "the landscape's aesthetic properties".